# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API - Create route with nullable parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following endpoint:

```
[Route("{id}/copy")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<CollectionView> Copy(long id, CollectionView? collectionView = null)
{
```

And I want to be able to call this endpoint by either providing a value for `collectionView` or `null`.

However, in my integration tests that call this endpoint, if I do not provide a body, the server returns 415 Unsupported Media Type.

```
//works
var copy = await PostAsync<CollectionView>($"{ApiBase}/{retValue.Id}/copy", new CollectionView { Name = "New Name" });

//415 unsupported media type
var copy = await PostAsync<CollectionView>($"{ApiBase}/{retValue.Id}/copy");
```

I tried specifying `[FromForm]` on the `CollectionView?` parameter as I've seen elsewhere, but then it was unable to parse the view I provided in the first integration test, all values came in as null.

How can I correctly configure my API endpoint to have an optional body parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `[FromBody]` instead of `[FromForm]`

```
[Route("{id}/copy")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<CollectionView> Copy(long id, [FromBody]CollectionView? collectionView = null)
```

`[FromForm]` only work when sending multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the asp.net core web api support null parameter. But the reason why your codes doesn't work is related with the your postasnyc method.

Since the Copy method require `application/json` as the request type, your postasny method doesn't set the right request type, this is the reason why you get the 415 error.

To solve this issue, I suggest you could try to modify the  PostAsync method which not include the CollectionView to also send the  `application/json` request.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Since I don't know your postasync method, I used rest client instead.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://localhost:5001/api/values/22/copy");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("undefined", "{}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```